# jssor transition builder - How to add code to existing slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, jssor

JSSOR is just wonderful! So the folks who developed this magic tool deserve to be thanked for this very, very much!

**My issue:** I have a slider where the pictures slide from left to right as default.

Taking this as a basis, I want to create that slider with a different transition. So I used that great JSSOR Transition Builder and created some custom transition.

I copied the code and now I have the question:

**Exactly where do I paste that code into?**

My guess is, that it must be added to the lines right after the line

```
var options = {
```

and before the beginning of the next nested bracket, which for me would be

```
$CaptionSliderOptions: {
```

Is that correct or has the new transition code to be pasted to another place?

Any help is greatly apprechiated!

Cheers,
Johannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 kind of transitions.

'slideshow transition' is slide level transition, it plays from 1 slide to another slide.
'caption transition' caption level transition, it plays caption within a slide.

'slideshow transitions' are specified as an array, e.g. var slideshow_transitions = [ { code1 }, { code2 }, { code3 } ]; See 'examples-jquery\slider-with-slideshow.source.html' example,

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow.html
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Fade
        { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
        ];

        var options = {
            $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

    });
</script>
```

'caption transitions' are specified as an array, and each transition is specified with name. e.g. var caption_transitions = []; caption_transitions["transition1"] = { code1 }; See 'examples-jquery\slider-with-caption.source.html' example,

```
<script>
    //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html
    //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-ui-definition.html#captiondefinition
    //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-caption-transition-viewer.html

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 800, $FlyDirection: 1, $Easing: $Jease$.$InCubic };
        _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 800, $FlyDirection: 2, $Easing: $Jease$.$InCubic };
        _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 800, $FlyDirection: 4, $Easing: $Jease$.$InCubic };
        _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 800, $FlyDirection: 8, $Easing: $Jease$.$InCubic };
        _CaptionTransitions["TL"] = { $Duration: 800, $FlyDirection: 5, $Easing: $Jease$.$InCubic };
        _CaptionTransitions["TR"] = { $Duration: 800, $FlyDirection: 6, $Easing: $Jease$.$InCubic };
        _CaptionTransitions["BL"] = { $Duration: 800, $FlyDirection: 9, $Easing: $Jease$.$InCubic };
        _CaptionTransitions["BR"] = { $Duration: 800, $FlyDirection: 10, $Easing: $Jease$.$InCubic };

        _CaptionTransitions["WAVE|L"] = { $Duration: 1500, $FlyDirection: 5, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$Linear, $Top: $Jease$.$OutWave }, $ScaleVertical: 0.4, $Round: { $Top: 2.5} };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|B"] = { $Duration: 600, $Clip: 8, $Move: true, $Easing: $Jease$.$OutExpo };

        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your quick and informative reply! It solved my issue.

Actually, "var _SlideshowTransitions" was missing from the slider-file I took as a template - hence I was puzzled where to copy the code into ... ;-)